# Error When Calling Data From SQLDatabase to ListView

Tags: android, sqlite

I have been trying to find the error in my project but I still have no luck.As I am new to programming I can't pin point this error. I have a list view within a dialog in my main project and what am doing here is trying to call data from my MySQL database browser to the list view. I have made a new project for this code as I don't want to mess up my main project with this code.

```
 package com.pdb.projectdb;

 import java.util.ArrayList; 

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class Main1Activity extends ListActivity {

  private static final String DB_NAME = "yourdb.sqlite3";

  //A good practice is to define database field names as constants
  private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
  private static final String FRIEND_ID = "_id";
  private static final String FRIEND_NAME = "name";

 private SQLiteDatabase database;
 private ListView listView;
 private ArrayList friends;

 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);

    //Our key helper
    ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this, DB_NAME);
    database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
    //That’s it, the database is open!
    fillFreinds();
      setUpList();
  }

  private void setUpList() {
  //We use a standard adapter and an element layout for brevity’s sake
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,   
 friends));
 listView = getListView();

 //Let’s set a message shown upon tapping an item
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
 int position,long id) {
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
 ((TextView) view).getText() +
      " could be Softeq's friend",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
 }
 }

 //Extracting elements from the database
  private void fillFreinds() {
 friends = new ArrayList<String>();
 Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {FRIEND_ID,
        FRIEND_NAME}, null, null, null, null, FRIEND_NAME);
 friendCursor.moveToFirst();
 if(!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
  do {
 String name = friendCursor.getString(1);
 friends.add(name);
 } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
  }
friendCursor.close();
 }
  }
```

XML.file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     tools:context=".Main1Activity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

DBHelper

```
     package com.pdb.projectdb;

     import java.io.FileOutputStream;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.InputStream;
     import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

     public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Path to the device folder with databases
    public static String DB_PATH;

    //Database file name
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
     public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
    return database;
    }

     public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
     super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
     this.context = context;
     //Write a full path to the databases of your application
     String packageName = context.getPackageName();
     DB_PATH = String.format("/data/data/newDB/databases/", packageName);
     DB_NAME = databaseName;
     openDataBase();
     }

    //This piece of code will create a database if it’s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
     if (!dbExist) {
     this.getReadableDatabase();
     try {
     copyDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
    throw new Error("Error copying database!");
     }
    } else {
      Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
    }
     }

     //Performing a database existence check
     private boolean checkDataBase() {
     SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
     try {
     String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
     Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
     }
     //Android doesn’t like resource leaks, everything should 
    // be closed
     if (checkDb != null) {
     checkDb.close();
       }
         return checkDb != null;
      }

    //Method for copying the database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    //Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
    //The stream source is located in the assets
    InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    //Path to the created empty database on your Android device
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
     OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //Copying the database
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
     }
    //Don’t forget to close the streams
       localDbStream.close();
    externalDbStream.close();
     }

     public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
     String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
     if (database == null) {
     createDataBase();
     database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
     SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
     }
      return database;
     }

     @Override
     public synchronized void close() {
     if (database != null) {
     database.close();
       }
     super.close();
       }
     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
     }
```

project view http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/1936/projectg.jpg

P.s my friend told me to not waste question on here as you can be banned please let me know if I am not formatting my question right

Thank you

http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/3965/fixq.jpg

Comment: You will have to post the logcat error for us to help you!

Comment: I cant run the project  so there is no logcat at the moment. or is there a way

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the picture. Can you tell us at what line the error is at? (not line number as we can't see the number here) but the piece of code that has the error.

Comment: EDIT: Hope the picture helps

Comment: You're not closing well your method. Eclipse tells you  that

Comment: I don't really know what you are saying about closing well your method? iv only been coding for a month so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace with this, i correctly formatted it for you

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main1Activity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "yourdb.sqlite3";

    // A good practice is to define database field names as constants
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "friends";
    private static final String FRIEND_ID = "_id";
    private static final String FRIEND_NAME = "name";

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList friends;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);

        // Our key helper
        ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this,
                DB_NAME);
        database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        // That’s it, the database is open!
        fillFreinds();
        setUpList();
    }

    private void setUpList() {
        // We use a standard adapter and an element layout for brevity’s sake
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friends));
        listView = getListView();

        // Let’s set a message shown upon tapping an item
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText()
                                + " could be Softeq's friend",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

    }

    // Extracting elements from the database
    private void fillFreinds() {
        friends = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {
                FRIEND_ID, FRIEND_NAME }, null, null, null, null, FRIEND_NAME);
        friendCursor.moveToFirst();
        if (!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String name = friendCursor.getString(1);
                friends.add(name);
            } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        friendCursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @coolcat Thats a different error all together! Look at tutorials on how to use ListActivity!

Comment: My internet was playing up so couldn't get back faster then i wanted too but i will tick answer to this question as you found my error.And i will look into list activity now thank you mario you was very helpful.

Comment: @coolcat No prob! Post another question if you're still stuck :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655079/multiple-activitys-on-listview-clickable